# Wrap Terraform commands

Tags: bash, terraform

I would like to wrap terraform apply and other command so that the right state are used for each AWS environment.

QA should use: `terraform apply -state=terraform.qa.tfstate`
The same goes for the other commands.

So bash script qa-apply should accept all [optional parameters](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/apply.html) and always use the QA state

```
# content of bash script qa-apply.sh
terraform apply -state=terraform.qa.tfstate
```

All environment are the same, but test has less servers in the clusters.

So what I want is this:

```
sh qa-apply.sh -var 'foo=bar'
```

should pass -var 'foo=bar' to:

```
terraform apply -state=terraform.qa.tfstate -var 'foo=bar'
```

Comment: It's going to be difficult to answer your question as it stands right now (in fact it's not currently a question) without knowing a lot more about how your Terraform configuration is set up. Can you add more information such as your folder structure and what you expect to happen when certain commands are run?

Comment: You already know what should be done, why not start to doing the job by yourself.

Comment: Note also that as of Terraform 0.9 there's a builtin way to use multiple states from a single config, using the `terraform env` command. https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/environments.html

Comment: @MartinAtkins . Best Practices: 

An environment alone `should not be used` to manage the difference between development, staging, and production

Comment: @MartinAtkins how would you mange state between different environments?

Comment: You could review the following solution, if you're sharing terraform on AWS: https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt